# Chatbox within/over Google JavaScript API (basemap) ?

Tags: infowindow

I'm looking to build a demo utilzing the Google Maps APIs and some sort of Chatbox software so that I can chat with users directly within my mapping application.

So essentially, anyone with access to my site (HTML5) would be able to enter a message. OR, what would be really cool is if you went to my hypothetical mapping site, saw other users on your map (via the browsers HTML geolocation) selected their "blue dot" location, had an infowindow pop up, then were able to enter a message within said infowindow.

I've been looking at different technologies (Firebase, Twilio), for real-time chatting, but haven't found any solid examples.

Could anyone offer recommendations/examples?